# PHP. Unable to consume remote web service using WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp

I am using WAMP server and I trying to read in a remote web service. I am receiving the following error -

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://example.com/search-api/search/devapi/coupons?format=xml&key=xxxxxxxx&searchloc=30043):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in C:\wamp\www\php\ws.php on line 7

Below is my code.

```
if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com/search-api/search/devapi/coupons?format=xml&key=xxxxxxxx&searchloc=30043') ) 
   { 
       echo 'unable to load XML file'; 
   } 
   else 
   { 
       echo 'xml loaded successfully';
   }
```

Comment: Contact `atti.com` support and ask them what actually is bad with your request.

Comment: The error you are getting means your xml url is not exist or invalid. Try to put url in browser and check is it valid xml or not.

Comment: It is a valid xml, and shows in my browser.  I am replacing the "xxxxxxx" with my api key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use `file_get_contents`

Try this -

```
print_r( simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents("http://pubapi.atti.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?searchloc=78597&term=pizza&format=xml&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=gmj3x7mhsh%22") ) );
```

**Solution 2**

```
function get_data($url){

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$url = 'http://pubapi.atti.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?searchloc=78597&term=pizza&format=xml&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=gmj3x7mhsh%22';

$result = get_data($url);

print_r(simplexml_load_string($result));
```

Comment: I tried the code (print_r( simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents("http://pubapi.atti.com/search-api/search/devapi/search?searchloc=78597&term=pizza&format=xml&sort=distance&radius=5&listingcount=10&key=gmj3x7mhsh")));  But it is not displaying anything.

Comment: That worked. Is there a way to parse it, to echo it out?

Comment: I am trying...if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_string($result) )
 {
    echo 'unable to load XML file';
 }
 else
 {
  //echo 'XML file loaded successfully <br />';  
    //print_r ($xml);
    echo $xml->searchResult->searchListings->searchListing[0];

 }

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out.   if( ! $xml = simplexml_load_string($result) )
 {
    echo 'unable to load XML file';
 }
 else
 {
  //echo 'XML file loaded successfully <br />';  
    //print_r ($xml);
    echo $xml->searchListings->searchListing[0]->businessName;

 }